# Thevenin Impedance for network with only dependent sources

Tags: impedance, thevenin, source

If a network has only dependent sources, you need to use a test current source or test voltage source (1v, 1a, something simple) since Zth = Voc/Isc doesn't work.

Is it valid to use a DC source as a test source with reactive components like an inductor and a capacitor to solve for the port impedance?

I need to solve for Z at terminals 1-1'.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not valid to use a DC source. The impedance will be a complex number with real and imaginary parts ( or magnitude and phase) and will be dependent on the frequency.

Comment: How should one go about solving for it then?

Comment: Your original suggestion of applying a source should work. If you tried this and it did not work can you provide details of what went wrong?

Comment: So should I apply a source with amplitude of 1 and the same phase as well as angular frequency? So it would be Vtest = 1cos(10^4*t)?

Comment: It's an interesting one. As long as your network behaves in a linear way then you can represent it as a thevenin source at a particular frequency. Applying 2 different voltages will allow you to determine the impedance. I think your source will act as a passive load I.e. zero current at zero applied voltage, so the thevenin equivalent will only be the impedance, not a source.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a DC source to find the impedance, as the impedance depends on the frequency. You should use a source which has the same frequency of interest.